# Preserving volume of cloned AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have cloned an AWS EC2 instance and attached it to an existing volume (of another EC2 instance).
Now I want to terminate the cloned instance but I want to keep the volume.

How do I make sure that the volume won't be deleted after I terminate the cloned instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've cloned an EC2 instance and need to verify the **Delete on Termination** setting, follow these steps:

- Navigate to the EC2 console.
- Select the cloned EC2 instance.
- Go to the Storage tab and confirm the "Delete on Termination"
  setting.

If it is set to **No**, deleting the cloned EC2 instance will not delete the associated volume.
However, if it is set to **Yes**, modifying **Delete on Termination** for a running server is only possible through AWS CLI.
The AWS Console allows this setting to be adjusted only during the server's launch.

To modify **Delete on Termination** using AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id <instance-id> --block-device-mappings file://mapping.json
```

In mapping.json, specify the device name, for example /dev/sda1 or /dev/xvda, and for --DeleteOnTermination, specify false.

```
[
  {
    "DeviceName": "device_name",
    "Ebs": {
      "DeleteOnTermination": false
    }
  }
]
```

Reference Link:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminate-instances-considerations.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Amazon EBS Volume in the EC2 management console. There is a **Delete on Termination** option against each volume that determines whether it will be deleted when the instance is Terminated.

By default, **root volumes will be deleted** (since they are mostly just copies of an AMI) but **additional volumes will not be deleted** by default. However, you can change those settings.

See also: [Preserve the EBS root volume when an Amazon EC2 instance terminates | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/deleteontermination-ebs)

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, You need to Open your AWS Console and Route to the `Amazon EBS Volume section` within the EC2 Management Console.

1. There you will find the option of `Delete on Termination`
2. Now update this option and once you terminate the AWS EC2 instance you will observe that the EC2 Instance will get deleted however the volume will stay.

For further reference please check --> https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/deleteontermination-ebs